# How do I add space between the tick labels and the graph in plotly (python)?

Tags: python, plotly

If I create a horizontal bar graph using plotly, the labels for each bar are right up against the graph. I'd like to add some space/pad/margin between the label and the graph. How can I do this?

Example:

```
import plotly.offline as py
import plotly.graph_objs as go
labels = ['Alice','Bob','Carl']
vals = [2,5,4]

data = [go.Bar(x=vals, y=labels, orientation='h')]

fig = go.Figure(data)
py.iplot(fig)
```

[image]

Comment: Just a small off-topic suggestion: Try matplotlib, offers much more ease

Comment: @Bazingaa I love matplotlib and have spent several years becoming very capable with it, but I need to serve up interactive plots to websites using flask, and unfortunately matplotlib isn't well suited for that (unless I've overlooked capabilities).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Just use parameter `pad` in `margin`. Check example from docs [here](https://plot.ly/python/setting-graph-size/).
Code:

```
import plotly.offline as py
import plotly.graph_objs as go

labels = ['Alice','Bob','Carl']
vals = [2,5,4]

data = [go.Bar(x=vals, y=labels, orientation='h')]

layout = go.Layout(
    margin=dict(
        pad=20
    ),
    title = 'hbar',
)
fig = go.Figure(data=data,layout=layout)

py.plot(fig, filename='horizontal-bar.html')
```

And plot should be looks something like that:
[image: Your plot]

Answer (score 8):

Shorter solution:

```
fig.update_layout(margin_pad=10)
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you could add some code like this.

```
import plotly.offline as py
import plotly.graph_objs as go
labels = ['Alice','Bob','Carl']
vals = [2,5,4]

data = [go.Bar(x=vals, y=labels, orientation='h')]
layout = dict(yaxis=dict(ticksuffix="   "))
fig = go.Figure(data=data,layout=layout)
py.iplot(fig)
```

add a suffix will fix this problem easily. I have checked the reference [plotly ref](https://plot.ly/python/reference/#layout-xaxis-tickmode), it also have more suitable key named `tickformat`, but it hard to use so I didn't use it.